# Running java in docker with oracle serverjre 8 can't find or load main class

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I am trying to run a java application in docker using the official oracle serverjre image. I am building it using gradle (which builds fine) then I build the docker container (which is also fine) but then when I try and start it it says "main-server_1 | Error: Unable to access jarfile /main-server.jar". Currently the application in just a main method with a println in it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8
WORKDIR /home

COPY ./build/libs/main-server-1.0.jar /home/main-server.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/main-server.jar"]
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

version = "1.0"
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Implementation-Title": "Main Server",
            "Implementation-Version": version,
            "Main-Class": "src/main/java.com.getsendus.server.Application"
        )
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://central.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.9.0"

    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0" 
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../lib/tools.jar")
}
```

Application.java:

```
package com.getsendus.server;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main Server Running");
    }
}
```

Log from docker up (docker-compose --verbose up main-server):

```
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/Users/robertwork/.docker/config.json', '/Users/robertwork/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: /Users/robertwork/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Auth data for https://index.docker.io/v1/ is absent. Client might be using a credentials store instead.
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'credsStore' section
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 568
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': ''}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.06.1-ce', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.38', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2018-08-21T17:29:02.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'true', 'GitCommit': 'e68fc7a', 'GoVersion': 'go1.10.3', 'KernelVersion': '4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.06.1-ce, ApiVersion=1.38, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=e68fc7a, GoVersion=go1.10.3, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs, Experimental=True, BuildTime=2018-08-21T17:29:02.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('sendusserverworkspace_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/sendusserverworkspace_default HTTP/1.1" 200 578
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': True,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-11-08T09:34:21.230596Z',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/info HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {'Architecture': 'x86_64',
 'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 'CPUSet': True,
 'CPUShares': True,
 'CgroupDriver': 'cgroupfs',
 'ClusterAdvertise': '',
 'ClusterStore': '',
 'ContainerdCommit': {'Expected': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e',
                      'ID': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e'},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('sendusserverworkspace_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/sendusserverworkspace_default HTTP/1.1" 200 578
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': True,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-11-08T09:34:21.230596Z',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=sendusserverworkspace', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dsendusserverworkspace%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=sendusserverworkspace', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dsendusserverworkspace%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=sendusserverworkspace', 'com.docker.compose.service=main-server', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dsendusserverworkspace%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dmain-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1123
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['java', '-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('sendusserverworkspace_main-server')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/sendusserverworkspace_main-server/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['java', '-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=sendusserverworkspace', 'com.docker.compose.service=main-server', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dsendusserverworkspace%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dmain-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1123
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('sendusserverworkspace_main-server')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/sendusserverworkspace_main-server/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['java', '-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['java', '-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: main-server>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: main-server>
Starting sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1 ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Container: sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1 (3611e7)>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Container: sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1 (3611e7)>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1 HTTP/1.1" 101 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x10f7968d0>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
Starting sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1 ... done
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: main-server>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=sendusserverworkspace', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
main-server_1                 | Error: Unable to access jarfile /main-server.jar
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dsendusserverworkspace%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x10f79f898>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['java', '-jar', '/main-server.jar'],
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3611e777b560c95c63f90e9b779e7ed2c9cfef61c570210711e93ae58317048a/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 1}
sendusserverworkspace_main-server_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: The COPY line copies the jar file to a specific path, which isn't the path referenced in the ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Doesn't WORKDIR set the default working directory? So the ENTRYPOINT would be executing in the WORKDIR directory.

Comment: True, but absolute paths always ignore the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove slash in Dockerfile
`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "main-server.jar"]`

Comment: It gives me the same result.

Comment: Will it work on your host? `java -jar ./build/libs/main-server-1.0.jar` Are you sure that file path is correct?

Comment: If I use that command on host it returns the same thing however it is in the correct path so there must be something wrong with my build.gradle?

Comment: Looks like file permission problem. You can check it by clean and regenerate jar or move it to another folder. However, I think in `build.gradle` you don't need to specify prefix `src/main` in `Main-Class`

Comment: That produced a different error now it is main-server_1 | Error: Unable to access jarfile /main-server.jar

Comment: Thanks for your help it ended up being a problem with build.gradle file not specifying classpath on top of that your right I also did not need to include src/main in the Main-Class I thought I read somewhere that I had to add that in guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the problem. It was a mixture of 2 things in the build.gradle the problems were that I put src/main before the package name in the Main-Class path, I had to add a Class-Path to the manifest as well as move the jar target below dependencies. here is the new file.

```
apply plugin: "java"

version = "1.0"

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://central.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.9.0"

    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0" 
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../lib/tools.jar")
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Implementation-Title": "Main Server",
            "Implementation-Version": version,
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
            "Main-Class": "com.getsendus.server.Application"
        )
    }
}
```